# XPATH Input Type Radio doesn't work c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, xpath, html-agility-pack

this my code

```
private DataTable ParseTable(string html)
    {
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        String[] datasc;
        String[] valueTemp = new String[30];
        int index;

        doc.LoadHtml("<table><tr><td><p><input id=\"ControlGroupScheduleSelectView_AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView_RadioButtonMkt1Fare7\" type=\"radio\" name=\"ControlGroupScheduleSelectView$AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1\" value=\"0~N~~N~RGFR~~1~X|QG~ 885~ ~~BTH~05/19/2014 07:00~KNO~05/19/2014 08:20~\" />Rp.445,000 ( N/Cls;4 )</p></td></tr></table>");

        for (int z = 0; z < 4; z++)
        {
            var getInputSchedule = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//input");
            datasc = new String[getInputSchedule.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < getInputSchedule.Count; i = i+1)
            {
                string removeClassFare = string.Empty;
                String[] selectValueSplit = getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["value"].Value.Split('|');
                valueTemp[i] = selectValueSplit[1];
                String[] getAlphaSC = selectValueSplit[0].Split('~');

                try
                {
                    index = getInputSchedule[i].ParentNode.InnerText.IndexOf("(");
                    if (index != -1)
                    {
                        removeClassFare = getInputSchedule[i].ParentNode.InnerText.Substring(0, index);
                        removeClassFare = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(removeClassFare)).Replace("??", "").Replace("Rp.", "").Trim();
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    //removeClassFare = getInputSchedule[i].ParentNode.InnerText;
                }


                if (!dt.Columns.Contains(getAlphaSC[1]))
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(getAlphaSC[1], typeof(string));
                }

                if (i == 0)
                {
                    datasc[i] = "<div align=\"center\"><input <input onclick='faredetail(this.value, this.name)' id=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["id"].Value + "\" type=\"radio\" value=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["value"].Value + "\" name=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["name"].Value + "\"><br>" + removeClassFare + "</div>";
                }
                else
                {
                    if (selectValueSplit[1].Equals(valueTemp[i - 1],StringComparison.Ordinal))
                    {
                        datasc[i] = "<div align=\"center\"><input <input onclick='faredetail(this.value, this.name)' id=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["id"].Value + "\" type=\"radio\" value=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["value"].Value + "\" name=\"" + getInputSchedule[i].Attributes["name"].Value + "\"><br>" + removeClassFare + "</div>";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                getInputSchedule[i].Remove();
            }

            datasc = datasc.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
            dt.Rows.Add(datasc);
        }

        return dt;
    }
```

if i run, error message "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.", but if i remove the ID of element like

`doc.LoadHtml("<table><tr><td><p><input type=\"radio\" name=\"ControlGroupScheduleSelectView$AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1\" value=\"0~N~~N~RGFR~~1~X|QG~ 885~ ~~BTH~05/19/2014 07:00~KNO~05/19/2014 08:20~\">Rp.445,000 ( N/Cls;4 )</p></td></tr></table>");`

Everything works ok.
Why does the ID attribute cause my XPath to fail?

pleasee..help..

thank you

Comment: What is `doc`? We can start guessing but it would be nice if you could help us a little more.

Comment: `HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();` @PatrickHofman

Comment: Your HTML is malformed. You have the `</tr>` tag before the `</td>` tag, when they should be the other way around. What happens if you fix those?

Comment: Your original code selects the node just fine when I try to run it. Is that really your actual code?

Comment: oups my mistake, i've edit the code, but still got null..
`<table><tr><td><p><input id=\"ControlGroupScheduleSelectView_AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView_RadioButtonMkt1Fare7\" type=\"radio\" name=\"ControlGroupScheduleSelectView$AvailabilityInputScheduleSelectView$market1\" value=\"0~N~~N~RGFR~~1~X|QG~ 885~ ~~BTH~05/19/2014 07:00~KNO~05/19/2014 08:20~\">Rp.445,000 ( N/Cls;4 )</p></td></tr></table>`  @JLRishe please help..

Comment: Where are you getting `null`? `SelectNodes` should usually not return a `null` (if anything, it returns an empty collection). Can you show us your code that uses `getInputSchedule`?

Comment: yes, this actual code..all html response i got from other website..this is bug or any mistake from my code ? if bug, any idea to remove id attribute from this node ? thank you @JLRishe

Comment: getting error of  `for (int i = 0; i < getInputSchedule.Count; i = i+1)` lines, because getInputSchedule got null from VS debugger

Comment: Like I said, `getInputSchedule` shouldn't be null under any circumstance. Could you please edit your question and show us more of your actual code, from the point where you retrieve the document up to where you use `getInputSchedule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stand corrected. `SelectNodes` does return `null` if it can't find any nodes.

But the behavior you are witnessing has nothing to do with the `id` attribute (in fact, removing the `id` attribute causes an exception to happen *sooner*), and everything to do with your code.

At the end of your inner loop, you are doing this:

```
getInputSchedule[i].Remove();
```

which removes the `<input>` element from the HTML document.

Your outer loop is set up to execute four times, so the second time it executes, the `input` element is already gone, and `doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table//input")` returns `null`, and that is the cause of your error.

I'm not really sure why you're removing the `input` elements from the document as you go through it, or why you're looping through the whole thing 4 times, but hopefully that gets you going in the right direction.

Comment: ouh i see, but how to remove current element (which mean only input that i loop, not all) ? i wanna remove input element one by one, so i think `getInputSchedule[i].Remove();` which remove one element, not all..

Comment: why i'm doing remove `getInputSchedule[i].Remove();`, because supposed i have two element, so i wanna remove input element that i've accessed with looping process..can i remove one by one of element in loop process ? thank you..

Comment: If you're looping through them, shouldn't the `[i]` allow you to access each one, one at a time? I still don't see a reason to remove them. How about if you just see what happens if you don't use that `Remove()` line?

Comment: ouh i know , now my code works oke..thank you @JLRishe for your time, of course you save my time..thanks again..

Comment: @IgiShellshock Great. If my post solved your issue, could you mark it as accepted (using with the checkmark icon)?